# proof that a system has at least one limit cycle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**The problem is:** Assuming that the parameters $a, b$ are real numbers and that $ab \neq0$, by transforming the system **using polar coordinates**, prove that
the system
$$x'=y+x(1-a^2x^2-b^2y^2)$$
$$y'=-x+y(1-a^2x^2-b^2y^2)$$
has at least one limit cycle in the phase plane.

**My proof is:** taking $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, we have $x^2+y^2=r^2$, i.e. $rr'=xx'+yy'$, so:
$$r'=r(1-a^2r^2\cos^2\theta-b^2r^2\sin^2\theta)$$
$$\theta'=-1.$$
So, $\theta = \theta(0)-t$ and $$1-a^2r^2\cos^2\theta-b^2r^2\sin^2\theta=0 \implies \frac{x^2}{b^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}=\frac{1}{(ab)^2}.$$
That means the system has a periodic solution which is ellipse.

**My question is** how to prove that it is limit cycle? or the system has another solution which is limit cycle?

Any hints are welcome!
Thank you!

Comment: Well, if you are suspicious that some $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are solutions of the system -- just plug them in. I recommend you to plug and check, though the disappointment awaits you on this path (they aren't solutions, sorry). This problem is a classical example where Poincare-Bendixson theorem works really nice: you have to show that there is an annulus that contains no equlibria and vector field points inward on both its boundary components (or outward). Then you are done: no equilibria inside that annulus, it's forward (or backward) flow invariant, thus it must have at least one limit cycle

Comment: @Evgeny So, as I understand I can take the annulus with inner circle(radius $>0$) smaller than the ellipse described above, and outer circle greater than the ellipse. Hence, using the equation for $r'$ above, we conclude that the orbits which start inside of inner circle will enter the annulus. Similarly, the orbits which start outside the largest circle will also enter the annulus. Using Poincare-Bendixson (since the only equilibrium is zero which is not inside of the annulus) we conclude that there exists at least one limit cycle. Am I right?

Comment: You are fantastically perfectly right :) btw, you can slightly weaken your reasoning: every trajectory that starts at the boundary of annulus, goes into it. To some extent, it doesn't really matter if *every* orbit that starts inside of inner circle will enter annulus. Only boundary is really important. That's the point of technique called "trapping region".

Comment: @Evgeny i understand now. Thank you very much! your explanation is excellent.

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad that it helped.